# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token = in Chrome

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am following an on-line tutorial to create a simple game in HTML using canvas and JavaScript. I tried to load what seemed to be perfectly fine code but nothing is showing up on the screen and I received an error in the console saying

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

This is the portion of my code that seems to be incorrect:

```
player = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        width: 20,
        height: 100,

        update = function() {},
        draw = function() {
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
        };
    };
```

PS - this error is showing up in Chrome.

Comment: You should definitely show us the previous - next lines

Comment: I dont know your exact code but I google and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699257/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-google-chrome

Comment: I just read that page, but I still don't know what to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `=` signs in a literal object definition, just replace them with `:`

```
    update : function() {},
    draw : function() {
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
```

As [amtd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/644786/atmd) specified in his answer, another error will show up after `draw` definition, because you are putting an extra `;` illegal token inside a literal object definition

Answer (score 1):

When setting functions as properties of an object, you still need to declare them with `:`, not `=`.

You also don't need the `;` after the function as that will give you an error once the `:` issue is fixed.

```
player = {
    x: null,
    y: null,
    width: 20,
    height: 100,
    update : function() {},
    draw : function() {
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
    }
};
```

Comment: You also need to remove the semicolon from the draw function

player = {
    x: null,
    y: null,
    width: 20,
    height: 100,

    update : function() {},
    draw : function() {
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
    }
};